# Why aren't instance variables defined in a controller's methods available in the corresponding partials?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, scope, partials

For example, given a basic controller such as:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @post = Post.all
  end
```

The instance variable `@post` is available in the view `posts/index.html.erb` but not the partial `posts/_index.html.erb`

My primary questions are: Why is this? and How can I define a method for a partial in a controller to for example, pass an instance variable?

On a more specific note:
I ask this because the way I am rendering data in a separate, primary view `welcome/index.html.erb` is via this posts partial. I have gotten around this limitation by directly calling the model with `Post.all` in the `posts/_index.html.erb` partial, but as far as I understand this ignores MVC architecture and severely limits me from developing more complex methods, unless I really break convention and write them into the view (which I assume may work but is poor design).

**Currently, @post is passing a nil to the partial symbol :post in welcome/index.html.erb**

Clearly I'm missing something, so any insight would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you

Relevant files:

```
views/
  posts/
    _index.html.erb
    _new.html.erb
    show.html.erb
  welcome/
    index.html.erb

controllers/ 
  posts_controller.rb
  welcome_controller.rb
```

posts/_index.html.erb

```
<% post.reverse.each do |post| %>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-body">
      <%= post.text %>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

posts/_new.html.erb

```
<%= form_for :post, url: posts_path do |f| %>
  <p id="post_box">
    <%= f.text_area :text %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.submit %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

posts/show.html.erb

```
<%= @post.text %>
```

welcome/index.html.erb  relevant portions (partials)

```
<%= render partial: "posts/index", locals: {post: @post} %>
<%= render partial: "posts/new" %>
```

controllers/posts_controller.rb

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  def new
  end

  def create
    @post = Post.new(post_params)

    @post.save
    redirect_to '/'
  end

  def show
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  end

  def index
    @post = Post.all
  end

  private
    def post_params
      params.require(:post).permit(:text)
    end

end
```

controllers/welcome_controller.rb

```
class WelcomeController < ApplicationController
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right that you're breaking MVC conventions by calling controller-level object lookups in your view.

When you call the render action on the partial you have a variety of arguments to send, one of which is a `locals` hash that takes a variable you want to pass directly into your partial.

It looks like this:

```
<%= render partial: "something", locals: {posts: @posts} %>
```

The rails guides are a great resource on the topic.  More on that [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials).

Comment: edit: going to read the passing locals and see if I can figure it out/check back if I can't find how to pass the data through locals.

Comment: Seem to be having issue- it doesn't mention anything about controllers. Where is it getting the instance variable's data from?

Comment: locals: {post: Post.all} works fine, but obviously defeats the purpose. @post is returning a nil- could it be because the partial is getting rendered into another view welcome/index instead of posts/index?

Comment: If I def index in the welcome controller the same as the posts controller, then I get a totally different error regarding the posts/_new partial, which means that perhaps it works but I need to resolve this other issue that for some reason this controller change causes?

Comment: it sounds like to me you haven't clearly defined your problem in your original question.  Set up the two scenarios for both ie. controller/view/partial so I can read through it.

Comment: Thanks for posting that - partials are independent of controllers.  You'll need to add @posts = Post.all in your `welcome#index` action

Comment: Adding that to the index of the welcome controller solved it, thanks! I didn't realize both partials rendering with different values for @post were I guess conflicting.