# Rendering partial from another controller breaks app - undefined method `text' for #<Post::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007fe74893b390>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I'm trying to render partials from another view `posts/_index` and `posts/_new` and controller Posts, into another view `welcome/index`. The posts/_index loads fine, but I can't figure out/understand why the posts/_new throws an error for the :text method which is only defined in the database migration, which I thought would be universally accessible.

This is where it references the error in the welcome/_new partial:

```
<%= form_for :post, url: posts_path do |f| %>
  <p id="post_box">
    <%= f.text_area :text %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.submit %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

And this is the working posts/_index partial:

```
<% post.reverse.each do |post| %>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-body">
      <%= post.text %>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

For reference the code is the same as: [Why aren't instance variables defined in a controller's methods available in the corresponding partials?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28184011/why-arent-instance-variables-defined-in-a-controllers-methods-available-in-the/28184129?noredirect=1#comment44738280_28184129)

except `controllers/welcome_controller.rb`

```
class WelcomeController < ApplicationController
  def new
  end

  def index
    @post = Post.all
  end

  private
    def post_params
      params.require(:post).permit(:text)
    end
end
```

Full trace:

```
app/views/posts/_index.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_posts__index_html_erb__2553516224846921857_70315677910360'
actionview (4.1.7) lib/action_view/template.rb:145:in `block in render'
activesupport (4.1.7) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:161:in `instrument'
actionview (4.1.7) lib/action_view/template.rb:339:in `instrument'
actionview (4.1.7) lib/action_view/template.rb:143:in `render'
actionview (4.1.7) lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:306:in `render_partial'
actionview (4.1.7) lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:279:in `block in render'
actionview (4.1.7) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:38:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.1.7) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.1.7) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (4.1.7) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
actionview (4.1.7) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:38:in `instrument'
actionview (4.1.7) lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:278:in `render'
actionview (4.1.7) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:47:in `render_partial'
actionview (4.1.7) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:21:in `render'
actionview (4.1.7) lib/action_view/helpers/rendering_helper.rb:32:in `render'
app/views/welcome/index.html.erb:118:in `_app_views_welcome_index_html_erb___2498066675045436064_70315678370540'
actionview (4.1.7) lib/action_view/template.rb:145:in `block in render'
activesupport (4.1.7) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:161:in `instrument'
actionview (4.1.7) lib/action_view/template.rb:339:in `instrument'
actionview (4.1.7) lib/action_view/template.rb:143:in `render'
actionview (4.1.7) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:55:in `block (2 levels) in render_template'
actionview (4.1.7) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:38:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.1.7) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.1.7) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (4.1.7) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
actionview (4.1.7) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:38:in `instrument'
actionview (4.1.7) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:54:in `block in render_template'
actionview (4.1.7) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:62:in `render_with_layout'
actionview (4.1.7) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:53:in `render_template'
actionview (4.1.7) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:17:in `render'
actionview (4.1.7) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:42:in `render_template'
actionview (4.1.7) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:23:in `render'
actionview (4.1.7) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:99:in `_render_template'
actionpack (4.1.7) lib/action_controller/metal/streaming.rb:217:in `_render_template'
actionview (4.1.7) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:82:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (4.1.7) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:32:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (4.1.7) lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb:32:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (4.1.7) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:25:in `render'
actionpack (4.1.7) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:16:in `render'
actionpack (4.1.7) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:41:in `block (2 levels) in render'
activesupport (4.1.7) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `block in ms'
/Users/lasernite/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.4/lib/ruby/2.1.0/benchmark.rb:294:in `realtime'
activesupport (4.1.7) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `ms'
actionpack (4.1.7) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:41:in `block in render'
actionpack (4.1.7) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:84:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
activerecord (4.1.7) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:25:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
actionpack (4.1.7) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:40:in `render'
actionpack (4.1.7) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:10:in `default_render'
actionpack (4.1.7) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
actionpack (4.1.7) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:189:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.1.7) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.1.7) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.1.7) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:113:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.7) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:113:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.7) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:229:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.1.7) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:229:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.7) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:229:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.1.7) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.7) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.1.7) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.7) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.1.7) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.7) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.1.7) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:86:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.7) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:86:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.1.7) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.1.7) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.1.7) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:31:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.1.7) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.1.7) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (4.1.7) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
actionpack (4.1.7) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.1.7) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in `process_action'
activerecord (4.1.7) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.1.7) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:136:in `process'
actionview (4.1.7) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
actionpack (4.1.7) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:196:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.1.7) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.1.7) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:232:in `block in action'
actionpack (4.1.7) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:82:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.7) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:82:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.1.7) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:50:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.7) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:73:in `block in call'
actionpack (4.1.7) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `each'
actionpack (4.1.7) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.7) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:678:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/head.rb:11:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:254:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:560:in `call'
activerecord (4.1.7) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
activerecord (4.1.7) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:621:in `call'
activerecord (4.1.7) lib/active_record/migration.rb:380:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.1.7) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:82:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.1.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:73:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:76:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
railties (4.1.7) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
railties (4.1.7) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.1.7) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (4.1.7) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
activesupport (4.1.7) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
railties (4.1.7) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.7) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:26:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:84:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
railties (4.1.7) lib/rails/engine.rb:514:in `call'
railties (4.1.7) lib/rails/application.rb:144:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
/Users/lasernite/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.4/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
/Users/lasernite/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.4/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
/Users/lasernite/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.4/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
```

Comment: Show the `code` how you rendered that partial file.

Comment: Code for one partial is same as before, just clarified. Added other partial. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The issue here is you are trying to print the text of all the posts, the text is attribute of single post.. That' why it's unable to find, 'text' attribute of association result(Post.all).**

```
def index
    @posts = Post.all
end


#index.html.erb 
 <% @posts.each do |post| %> 
  <%= post.text %> 
 <% end %>
```

Assuming you are trying to list all the posts & create a new post being in the welcome/index, you need to modify your index action like this :

```
  def index
   @posts = Post.all  #this one to list posts
   @post = Post.new  #this initializer will be used in your _new partial.
  end
```

Comment: But as you show above, the code has an .each method so that it works fine. The issue is with the _new partial right? Not the _index? Thanks!

Comment: As in, the issue isn't with rendering the posts, it's with rendering the form for making posts specifically at the line it can't find :text: <%= f.text_area :text %>

Comment: What's the action it's hitting to reach the partial? it's new action or index ?

Comment: Just updated my answer assuming in your welcome/index page you are listing all the posts. Assuming you have a new post creation form in the same page, try initializing @post = Post.new, hope that works.

Comment: Worked thanks- can you reference any source I can read on understanding what you mean by 'what's the action it's hitting to reach the partial'? It seemed to me like def new should have been the relevant place in the controller not the def index, which has me confused now. Thanks so much Ajay!

Comment: So it works with the exact same code as the other controller except changing the def index so that it's posts = Post.all and def create has post = Post.new(post_params) post.save redirect_to '/'. My question is, why was the index method interfering with the new/create? Is it because of the way I moved the local variable into the partials or partials have accessing to the full controller instance variables or?

Comment: You are good to go with following example: http://www.sitepoint.com/building-your-first-rails-application-views-and-controllers/
you can join me in chat, to talk regarding your query.